# @Binding - passing FetchedResults, single Entities, to SubViews in Core Data + SwiftUI

Tags: core-data, swiftui, binding

I just want to pass a binding to an Core Data - Entity to a SwiftUI SubView screen inside a ForEach Loop with a binding, so I have access to edit properties of the Entity, I can save my context and get automatic updated views..

how can I achieve something like this:

```
ContentView {
  @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) private var viewContext
  @FetchRequest(entity:ToDo.entity(), sortDescriptors: [])
  private var toDoItems: FetchedResults<ToDo>

  ... the following part is what I need:

  ForEach(toDoItems) { (item:ToDo) in
    NavigationLink(
      destination: MyEditView($item),
      ...
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to set an `@ObservedObject var item: ToDo`. Your CoreData entity is a class that conforms to `ObservableObject` and will force a view update when any property is changed in it.

```
struct NextView: View {
  @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var managedObjectContext
  @ObservedObject var item: ToDo
  
  var body: some View {
    Button(action: {
      item.name = "New value"
      if managedObjectContext.hasChanges {
        do {
            try self.managedObjectContext.save()
            print("SAVED CONTEXT")
        } catch let error {
            print("Error: SAVING CONTEXT \(error), \(error.localizedDescription)")
        }
    }, label: {
      Text("\(item.name)")
    })
  }
}
```

You can now make any change you want and save the context when needed

Comment: thank you, this pointed me to the right direction!